# Methods of computing the derivative of vector norms

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am very new to norms. Except the basic definitions and properties of the norm, I don't know too much about it. Now, I am very interested in computing the derivative of the norms. So, I am wondering if anyone could show me some methods(or sources) of computing the derivative of the following norms:

1. $\frac{d||x||_p^m}{dx}, m,p\in\mathbb{N},x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
2. $\frac{d||as+b||_p^m}{ds},m,p\in\mathbb{N}, a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n,s\in \mathbb{R}$

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: What does $d/dx$ mean when $x \in \mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a normal derivative won't get you anything interesting.  You should look at [Partial Derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) and [Vector Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus).